# what is effect of deadlock on other processes which are not involve in deadlock?

Tags: operating-system, deadlock

I am not finding the exact answer that if deadlock  occurres in the system then the  system will  stop working or some of the processes which are not involved in the deadlock can keep executing.

When deadlock occures Then system will go in deadlock or only that processes which are in deadlock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only that processes which are in deadlock will.

And it's one of the reasons that most of modern personal computers ignore it.

(Since deadlock prevention,avoidance,detection and recovery are expensive)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the only process which goes in the deadlock is affected, not the other one as generally the most of the operating systems like Windows and Linux uses the deadlock ignorance(Ostrich algorithm) method to avoid the deadlock in the system, while on the other hand, other algorithms such as deadlock prevention/detection/avoidance are expensive to implement and its somewhat about an unrealistic assumption that how much a process is gonna need the amount of resource to execute completely, generally deadlock avoidance/detection is used in database software, for example, many database operations involve locking several records, Ergo no other processes are affected except the process which entered into an infinite blocking/starvation(Deadlock).